# Covariant return types and dispatch

Tags: c++, covariance, virtual-functions

I'm confused by this simple program:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Base {
  virtual ~Base() {}
  virtual Base* concrete() { cout << "concrete returning base - "; return this;}
  void stat() { cout << "I'm a BASE\n";}
};

struct Derived: Base {
  Derived* concrete() override { cout << "concrete returning derived - "; return this;}
  void stat() { cout << "I'm a DERIVED\n";}
};


int main() {
  Base * bd = new Derived;
  bd->stat();  // prints: "I'm a BASE"
  bd->concrete()->stat(); //prints: "concrete returning derived - I'm a BASE"

  delete bd;
  return 0;
}
```

Why doesn't the last line print `concrete returning derived - I'm a DERIVED`? What's going on here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're misunderstanding the utility of the covariant return type... it kicks in when the calling context knows it's dealing with a `Derived`-type object:

```
Derived d;
d->concrete()->stat();
```

In your case, `concrete` is called on a `Base*` so although it's dispatched polymorphically and returning a `Derived*`, that pointer is treated as a `Base*` in the calling context, and it's the `Base*` static type that determines the static dispatch to `stat()`.